# Creating variable in Testcomplete 12 for SWTObject item

Tags: java, python-2.7, swt, testcomplete

I'm currently working on a project where our application is executed as standalone jar, written on SWTObjects.
From end-user perspective I have to create automated scripts. We are evaluating the Testcomplete ver 12, however I'm having really hard time to create a variable based on Tree item.  To make things worse, the item (in our case user names)  caption has a dynamic string, once the username status changes , ex. testuser1 (NewDate Oct 13 2000). Since I might have multiple users with different Newdates listed, I'm trying to set a variable based only on the partial string "NewDate, ignoring the usernames and the rest of the string(the actual Date values). 
In nutshell,  script should find all  Tree items that have text "NewDate" attached, select them, store as variables,  proceed to next steps, re-select the same items using variables.

Could anyone provide my some guidance, perhaps pictures. I'm having hard time to understand how to do it.
programming lang used:python

Thank you
Seb

Comment: You mentioned that your project used SWT and the expected outcome is a jar file, but you want to use python as programming language? is python used for the automated test scripts?

Comment: I'm struggling to identify your question, what you are looking for is a way to identify multiple objects associated to a single execution of a test script?

Comment: What exactly you want to store: a link to an actual object, the name of the object, the text of the object, etc. Also, next steps where you want to use the stored data are separate test items, script routines or projects?